# Console Terminus Font Size in Slackware?

Tags: command-line, console, fonts, slackware

I am running Slackware 14.1 mostly from the command line on a 1366x768 monitor (using a vesa mode appropriate for the resolution, 0x34c if it matters, giving me a screen resolution of 1366x768x32 in the CLI) and find the font size of the terminus font I have selected `lat2 terminus16` to be just a little too small to read comfortably. I like the font but would like to use a larger size e.g. 18 or 20.

`setconsolefont` displays only that size of the terminus font.

How do I install, or if it is already installed, set a larger size for use?

Comment: It appear you have an answer at Linux Questions!: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/console-terminus-font-size-4175489795/